# Define a verbose name for an entire Django model

Tags: django, django-models, naming-conventions, verbosity

I want to create a model named Model.  I'm pretty sure this isn't allowed, so I'm forced to use some other term for the model name.  Let's say I call it Mdl.  However from the user perspective, I want to still refer to the table as Model.  Is there a way to define a verbose name for the entire model Mdl the same way you can for model fields?  In my templates, I reference the name of the current table at the top of the document:

```
{{ model }}
```

which gets passed from a view.  If I can't define a verbose name, then I'm going to have to call some function every time to translate Mdl's name to Model *just* for that one table.  Does anyone have an alternate suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`Meta.verbose_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/options/#verbose-name)

Comment: Awesome!  Any idea how I access this from a template given a model?